# MySQL Add Total at bottom of search result if there is one or more records has been found

Tags: mysql

I have below SQL statement to generate a total at bottom of search result but I do not want to display Total if there is no record has been found.  Need help on below Statement.

```
SELECT Member_ID, Order_Total, Shipping_Cost, TAX FROM Order Where                 
Order_Total > 100
UNION (
SELECT "Total" as Member_ID, sum(Order_Total) as Order_Total, sum(Shipping_Cost) as Shipping_Cost, sum(TAX) as TAX FROM Order Where                 
Order_Total > 100);
```

Comment: Should the total only be for `Order_Total > 100`?

Comment: each order's total need more than $100

Comment: I mean the first query is only returning rows where order_total > 100. Should the second query only sum those same rows?

Comment: yes, I am going to make a change

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word, so you're not quite telling us the whole truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `UNION`, you can use the `WITH ROLLUP` option to make an automatic total. If the query doesn't select any rows, the result will be empty.

```
SELECT IFNULL(Member_ID, 'Total') AS Member_ID, Order_Total, Shipping_Cost, TAX
FROM (
    SELECT Member_ID, sum(Order_Total) as Order_Total, sum(Shipping_Cost) as Shipping_Cost, sum(TAX) as TAX 
    FROM `Order` 
    Where Order_Total > 100
    GROUP BY Order_ID
    WITH ROLLUP) AS x
```

Another way is to keep your `UNION`, but add a `HAVING` clause to the second query.

```
SELECT Member_ID, Order_Total, Shipping_Cost, TAX 
FROM `Order` 
Where Order_Total > 100
UNION (
SELECT "Total" as Member_ID, sum(Order_Total) as Order_Total, sum(Shipping_Cost) as Shipping_Cost, sum(TAX) as TAX 
FROM `Order` 
Where Order_Total > 100
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0);
```